# What is the term used for space of analytic functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, terminology

I deal with analytic functions in the unit disc represented as the series 
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty u_n z^n$, where the coefficients $u_n$ satisfy the condition
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^\alpha|u_n| < \infty$ 
with $\alpha > 0$.

Does there exist any commonly used name for the spaces of such functions?